# Remove and return single value from parallel, mutable map

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am wrapping a mutable parallel map in Scala and would like to remove and return a single value from the map. Current implementation is as follows...

```
class MyContainer[O] {

  def remove(uuid: UUID): Option[O] = backingStore.get(uuid) match {
      case result @ Some(item) => backingStore -= item.uuid; result
      case None => None
  }

  private[this] val backingStore: parallel.mutable.ParHashMap[UUID, O]

}
```

...but this seems inelegant.  Is there a more idiomatic way to accomplish this? Perhaps without pattern matching?

Comment: Mutable parallel sounds like a recipe for disaster... are you sure there's not better way? E.g. via a TrieMap?

Comment: @Reactormonk The plan is that only a single main thread will access the container, but that container methods will be parallelized. But I take your point and will look into the TrieMap (which already has a `remove` method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collect` on the `Option` returned by the `get` method

```
backingStore.get(uuid).collect { case Some(value) =>
 backingStore -= item.uuid
 value
}
```